# discord.js instagram account scrape

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, discord, discord.js

i am trying to fix this code to show stats about a instagram account (followers, user, following, posts, etc) but the code is broken, and im not sure what to do.

the code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const instagram = require("instagram-api.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "ig (in development)",
    category: "search",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send(`Please Enter a Channel Name`)
        }
        let url, response, account, details;
        try {
            url = `https://instagram.com/${args[0]}`;
            response = await axios.get(url)
            account = response.data
            details = account.graphql.user
        } catch (error) {
            return message.channel.send(`Not An Account`)
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${details.is_verified ? `${details.username} <a:verified:727820439497211994>` : ` ${details.username}`} ${details.is_private ? '' : ''} `)
            .setDescription(details.biography)
            .setThumbnail(details.profile_pic_url)
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: "Total Posts:",
                    value: details.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count.toLocaleString(),
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Followers:",
                    value: details.edge_followed_by.count.toLocaleString(),
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Following:",
                    value: details.edge_follow.count.toLocaleString(),
                    inline: true
                }
            )
        await message.channel.send(embed)

    }
}



module.exports.help = {
name: "insta",
description: "This Command Allows You To Search For instagram Accounts!",
usage: "b!insta <instagram user>",
accessableby: "Everyone",
aliases: []
};
```

the error:

```
(node:7872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /home/runner/DraconianJSBot-1/node_modules/@sapphire/fetch/dist/index.js:76
    return __privateGet(this, _json) ?? __privateSet(this, _json, JSON.parse(this.body));
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/DraconianJSBot-1/node_modules/instagram-api.js/dist/index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
(node:7872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7872) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

im not quite sure what to do so any help would be amazing! you dont have to though ofc, im just new to this stuff so i need a little bit of assistance

Comment: A wild guess is that you are using an outdated version of Node.js. Try to upgrade it to the latest version on https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using a outdated version of Node.js, where the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) isn't available yet.

In order to be able to use it, you have to upgrade to at least version 14.* as you can see from the official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility).

### Downloads

- [16.13.2](https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.13.2/node-v16.13.2-x64.msi) - Long Term Support (LTS) - Recommended for most users
- [17.4.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/v17.4.0/node-v17.4.0-x64.msi) - Latest features